# Правильная отладка приложения. Узнать какой класс занял файл

Tags: c#, отладка

**Доброго времени суток!**

*Столкнулся с проблемой, с которой не могу сам справиться уже десяток часов.*

Суть проблемы: есть достаточно большое приложение и кучкой классов. Разные классы работают с одним и тем же файлом, но по-разному. Кто-то открывает его как бинарник, кто-то просто переименовывает,кто-то выполняет в нем запросы как в базе данных,кто-то крепит и изменяет альтернативные потоки... В общем работа бурлит. При некоторой последовательности действий наблюдаю проблему, что не могу переименовать файл. Ловлю исключение, и успешно его обрабатываю.

Так в общем вопрос сводится к тому: могу ли в точке исключения определить объект класса, который "забыл" или не смог закрыть подключение? Или сидеть и искать все места, логируя открытие и закрытие файла?

Исходники обрабатываются в студии 2008, но для выяснения причин есть под рукой все варианты студии с 2005, отладчик win dbg, doctor watson... Да и поставить что не проблема.

**Очень прошу о помощи, заранее, как всегда - благодарства!**

Comment: Так просто не получится: даже если вы найдёте объект `File` или `FileStream`, который на самом деле заблокировал файл, найти другие объекты, которые создали и не закрыли stream, не так просто. (Хотя хороший профилировщик может и помочь.)

---
Попробуйте Process Explorer. В нём можно видеть, какие хэндлы на файл держит процесс. Таким образом вы можете вызвать функцию и посмотреть, закрылся ли хэндл по окончанию её работы. Когда найдёте виноватую функцию, зайдите в неё и точно так же протестируйте её подфункции. Легко не будет :(

Comment: Судя по описанным симптомам, больной лечению не поддается.

Такое приложение отладить не удастся. Проще выбросить и написать новое (только спроектировать, включая структуры внешних данных, сначала не забудьте и грамотно тестировать модули в процессе их написания, а то дубликат получите).

Comment: @VladD, пробовал посмотреть процессмонитором, все close вроде выполняются.

Хотя пошагово, просмотрев код, склоняюсь к строчке вызова SystemDiagnostic.Process где вызывается запуск стороннего приложения с ожиданием его завершения. Может быть ожидание заканчивается раньше чем  файл освободился?..

Comment: Вообще, если примерно судить по коду, выполняется как-то так:

* Открыли файл
* Дешифровали файл
* Закрыли файл
* Открыли файл, работаем как с базой данных. Сохраняем данные
* Закрываем файл, сохраняем альтернативные потоки
* Открываем файл, дописываем информацию
* Закрываем файл
* Открываем файл, шифруем
* Закрываем файл
* Переименовываем файл (вот тут ошибка)

PS: Если каждую функцию отдельно выполнить - то все ОК проходит.

Comment: @pincher1519: А если сделать breakpoint перед началом последнего пункта («переименовываем файл»), и посмотреть Process Explorer'ом, есть ли открытые хендлы? А если сделать перед переименованием паузу в 10 секунд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за отклик, нашел в чем проблема.

Подключения все шли через локальный сервер firebird. Во время сохранения в базу данных отсутствовала проверка, что подключение уже с базой установлено, и просто производилось открытие нового подключения. При этом, видима, объект подключения старый оставался активным, и мусоросборщик его не дропал, хотя уже ни один объект на это подключение не ссылался. Добавил проверку, что подключение установлено, и не открывал лишнее. Слава Богу, что все просто решилось =) Как говорится - утро вечера мудренее.

В общем по поводу непосредстенно вопроса, узнать через отладку невозможно, какие объекта ссылаются на тот или иной ресурс, и какие еще живы или готовятся к убийству?

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), я так и не нашел, где в process explorer можно посмотреть открытые хэндлы. Хотя по факту, на тот момент файл занимала не моя программа, а сервер. Обнаружил проблему через информацию о сервере через IBExpert, что мое приложение 2 коннекта держит к базе.

[@avp](/users/232/avp), после года разработки, оборачиваясь на то, что получилось и как писалось уже с новыми знаниями и полученными шишками - всегда хочется переписать =) И чем быстрее учишься, тем быстрее приходит ощущение, что пора переписывать то, что писал.

[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh), все действия производятся последовательно, нет случайного срабатывания, хотя все и производится в разных классах. В один момент работу производит только один класс, остальные объекты либо уничтожены, либо закрыли подключения и ждут новой команды. При передачи управления из одного объекта в другой обязательным условием является освобождение ресурсов с которыми этот объект работал.

Comment: Стоп, стоп. Подключения к базе надо явно закрывать через `Dispose` как только они не нужны, не надеясь на garbage collector (который имеет право вообще никогда не запуститься, если у вас много памяти). Ну или повторно использовать, но тогда у вас должна быть ссылка на открытое подключение.

---
В Process Explorer зайдите в меню View и включите Show lower pane, затем Lower pane view -> Handles. Кроме того, там есть меню Find -> Find Handle or DLL, в котором можно задать поиск программы, блокирующей файл.

Comment: Подключение закрываю, но ручками при необходимости. Диспоуз не вызовется до уничтожения объекта, который я не уничтожают, ибо он мне ещё нужен, только освобождал файл.

Про эксплорер спасибо, годная утилита, не пользовался ранее ей.

Comment: Хм, а почему вы переоткрываете закрытое соединение? Мне кажется, это неправильно: надо открывать соединение, потом закрывать и уничтожать объект. Когда нужно соединение снова, создавайте новый объект.

---
Пожалуйста!

Comment: При создании объекта ему передаётся подключение, которым потом объект управляет. Если меняется строка подключения, то перечитываются свойства объекта путём считывания записей. Потому происходит только открытие и закрытие. Если грохать объект, то он заново будит считывать данные из базы.

Comment: Ну, если подключение было закрыто, данные надо всё равно перечитывать, они имели право поменяться.

Comment: @Vladd, в данном случае нет. Только один класс вносит изменения данных в таблицы базы.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, конечно же, такого рода "бурлящая" работа с одним единственным файлом нехороша, так как вероятность того, что в одном из ваших классов произойдет, например, запись, а в другом в это же время чтение из файла достаточно велика. В вашем случае следовало бы использовать некий промежуточный кэш, из которого уже в определенный момент осуществлялся бы перенос информации в файл. Хотя, вашего проекта я не знаю, так что свой нос в его архитектуру совать мне не следует.

Раз вы ловите исключение, возникающее в одном из классов, взаимодействующих с файлом, то, если классов разумное число( в пределах 10 ), вы могли бы "напряженный момент" в каждом из них обернуть в конструкцию `try->throw->catch` и в случае возникновения исключительной ситуации генерировать уникальное исключение( например, текстовое сообщение ).

Надеюсь, ваша проблема была понята мною верно.

**P.S**  Все же знайте, что подобного рода архитектура шатка и можен однажды с треском рухнуть, положив всю систему...